# Strange issue with uiview animation and Alamofire on POST login request

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, alamofire

I've created a simple login request

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let result = response.result.value
            print(result)
            let token = response.response?.allHeaderFields["Access-Token"] as! String
            print(token)
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toFirstOnboardingFromLogin", sender: nil)
        }
        else{
            self.emailTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.9).CGColor
            self.passwordTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.9).CGColor
            self.emailTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            self.passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            self.passwordTextField.shake()
            self.emailTextField.shake()
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toFirstOnboardingFromLogin", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

The segue/animation works perfectly if the result returns failure (incorrect login credentials) but if the user logs in correctly, the animation appears glitchy and somewhat offset. Any ideas? It's the same line of code to perform the segue, so I'm clueless as to what it could be.

EDIT: Tried performing the segue on the main thread as suggested - no luck

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let result = response.result.value
            print(result)
            let token = response.response?.allHeaderFields["Access-Token"] as! String
            print(token)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                //PerformSegue here ...
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toFirstOnboardingFromLogin", sender: nil)

            }
        }
        else{
            self.emailTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.9).CGColor
            self.passwordTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.9).CGColor
            self.emailTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            self.passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            self.passwordTextField.shake()
            self.emailTextField.shake()
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toFirstOnboardingFromLogin", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I've also tried using dispatch_sync with no luck

Comment: remove print statements and then try.

Comment: tried it and it made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was nothing to do with Alamofire or the main thread getting blocked! I had an earlier function which had UIView.commitAnimations() within a conditional, but it had the .beginAnimations outside the conditional. So the animation would always start but never be committed hence the choppiness of the animation.

Issue was easily fixed by placing the commit animations outside of the conditional!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is blocking your thread; try performing seque on main thread.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                 //PerformSegue here ...
             }
    }
```